# What gallery is Michelangelo's David in?

Tags: tickets, italy, museums, florence, artworks

I want to go to see Michelangelo's David sculpture. All the sources on-line say it's in the *Accademia Di Belle Arti Di Firenze*. When I go to the [official site](http://www.b-ticket.com/b-ticket/uffizi/default.aspx) it gives the option to buy tickets to different places, with different prices:

- The Accademia Gallery
- The Uffizi Gallery
- The Palatine Gallery and Royal Apartments
- Bargello Museum
- Medici Chapels Museum
- Giardino di Boboli
- Museo di San Marco
- Museo Archeologico
- Opificio delle Pietre Dure

Which of these tickets do I need if I want to see only the statue of David?

Comment: So, the statue is at the Accademia, but if you are in Florence and don't go to the Uffizi, you are robbing yourself.  The Uffizi has lots of works by Michelango, Da Vinci, Botocelli, etc...  If you are going to be in Florence, and if you have the desire to see Renaisance art, then it makes sense to get tickets for *both* of the top two on your list...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I went straight to Wikipedia for this.  Their article [David (Michelangelo)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_%28Michelangelo%29) states:

> David is a masterpiece of Renaissance sculpture created between 1501
>   and 1504, by the Italian artist Michelangelo. It is a 5.17-metre (17.0
>   ft) marble statue of a standing male nude. The statue represents
>   the Biblical hero David, a favoured subject in the art of Florence.
>   Originally commissioned as one of a series of statues of prophets to
>   be **positioned along the roofline of the east end of Florence
>   Cathedral**, the statue was instead placed in a public square, outside
>   the Palazzo della Signoria, the seat of civic government in Florence,
>   where it was unveiled on 8 September 1504.
>
> Because of the nature of the hero that it represented, it soon came to
>   symbolize the defense of civil liberties embodied in the Florentine
>   Republic, an independent city-state threatened on all sides by more
>   powerful rival states and by the hegemony of the Medici family. The
>   eyes of David, with a warning glare, were turned towards Rome. **The
>   statue was moved to the Accademia Gallery in Florence in 1873, and
>   later replaced at the original location by a replica.**

So although you could see a replica at the Florence Cathedral, the real deal is currently at the Accademia Gallery, where it has stood since 1873.

Answer (score 8):

The [Accademia Gallery](http://www.polomuseale.firenze.it/en/musei/?m=accademia) (Galleria dell'Accademia).